# Customer Journey testing

Tags: documentation, user-journey, customer, journey-map, users-tests

I'm new inside UX/CX design field, and I would like to know more info about customer journey mapping.

I know that this process is to map the current customer journey also emotional mapping to find out in which step the customer is not satisfied and then improve the journey.

My question is, is there any technique to test and document the results of the new customer journey?

Thank you guys in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is creating a customer journey map of the current situation and of the desired outcome.

Implement changes and do research after appropriate amount of time. (usability testing or interviewing, whatever suits your situation best)

Create a customer journey of the new situation so you can visually compare the three situations.
Is there improvement over the old situation?
Did we reach the desired outcome?

Hope this helps.
Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your help Paul.

I have some other team members, do you think that could be a good idea creating a customer journey mapping collaborating system? 

I mean, once I have a customer journey, they could check it and give their comments, I believe it could be a way to test it right the way without implementing it.

What is your opinion about it?

Comment: A customer journey map is very suitable for collaboration. Because of it's simple and visual nature it can be understood by management, designers and developers alike. Testing the new customer journey without implementing it could be possible, but it really depends on your product or service. You could try reenacting it. You might need to create a prototype or not, again, that depends on your product or service. Just ask someone to play a customer. It could be your friend, your mother, your grandmother or preferably somebody who is not biased.